# apply function with multiple arguments and variables

Tags: r, apply

How do I provide multiple parameters and variables to an apply function? I'd like to pass vectir `c(1, 2)` to argument `l` and varaibles `c(x, x1`) to argument `k`.

**Desired Output** should have four columns instead of two

**Example**

```
library(zoo)
datt <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100),
           x2 = rnorm(100))
mapply(function(l, k) c(rollmean(datt[,k], l), rep(NA, l-1)),
       c(1, 2),
       c("x", "x2"))
```

**Output**

```
           x         x2
1 -0.2688922  0.9506357
2  0.1402062  0.7324266
3  0.1391136 -1.7412695
4  1.4542990  2.1617833
5 -0.9409344  2.0495386
6 -0.8309520  0.6403896
```

Comment: If the `l` statnds for the 'k' argument, there would be only two column output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have to apply the 'k' for multiple columns, pass the columns in a `list`

```
res <- do.call(cbind, Map(function(l, k) rollmean(datt[,k], l, fill = NA), 
           1:2, list(c("x", "x2"))))
```

However, we don't an extra argument as the need is for looping the `k` argument and the subset of data remains the same

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(1:2, rollmean, x = datt[c("x", "x2")], fill = NA))
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I need to retain the `l-1` because I lag the rollmean by 1.

Comment: @Vedda Ok, then you can remove the `fill = NA` and use your `rep(NA, l-1)`

Comment: In `rollapply` the `width=` can be a one component list containing a vector of offsets. This would avoid the `rep`.  I have shown that in my revised answer but that approach could be incorporated here too.

Answer (score 2):

Create a grid 4x2 grid of the 4 combinations of `l` and `k` and then `mapply` over that.  Note that we can simplify `fun` slightly using `fill = NA` .  Note that the `width` argument of `list(1:l)` means pass offsets 1 through l to the mean.  Offset 1 is the next value and offset 2 is the value after the next value.

```
fun <- function(l, k) rollapply(datt[, k], list(1:l), mean, fill = NA)
g <- expand.grid(l = 1:2, k = c("x", "x2"))
mapply(fun, g[[1]], g[[2]])
```

### Update

Based on comments by poster clarifying intent changed `rollmean` to `rollapply` with indicated width.